Sum of two closed subspaces in a Banach Space
I am working on a functional analysis question:

Let $X$ be a Banach space, and $Y,Z$ be closed subspaces. If $X=Y+Z$, show that there is $C>0$ such that every $x\in X$ has a representation $x=y+z$ for $y\in Y$ and $z\in Z$, and $\|y\|+\|z\|\le C\|x\|$

I know that this question is trivial if $Y\cap Z=\{0\}$: just apply the bounded inverse theorem and we are done. However, I don't know what to do if $Y\cap Z$ is non-trivial.

In that case apply the open mapping theorem.

@axif00 Can you give me more hints? I thought about the open mapping theorem and still don't know how I can use it

Why is there a downvote on this post? Do people even read the post or understand the context before they spam the downvote button?

@Mr.GandalfSauron Best to ignore the noise here.

Consider the space $Y \times Z$ and the map $T$ from the other answer.
Then, as $T$ is a surjective continuous linear map, by the open mapping theorem we have that $T$ is open.
Hence, there exists a constant $c>0$ such that
$$
B_X(0,c) \subset T(B_{Y \times Z}((0,0),1));
$$
meaning that for every $x \in X$ such that $\|x\|<c$ there exists $y \in Y$ and $z \in Z$ such that $\|y\|+\|z\|<1$ and $x=y+z$.
Thus, given $x \in X$, if $x \neq 0$,
$$
\frac{c}{2\|x\|}x = y_1+z_1
$$
for some $y_1 \in Y$ and $z_1 \in Z$ such that $\|y_1\|+\|z_1\| < 1$.
Therefore, $x=y+z$, where
$$
y = \frac{2\|x\|}{c}y_1 \in Y, \qquad z = \frac{2\|x\|}{c}z_1 \in Z
$$
and
$$
\|y\|+\|z\| = \frac{2\|x\|}{c}(\|y_1\|+\|z_1\|) < \frac{2\|x\|}{c} = C\|x\|, \qquad C := \frac 2c.
$$

(+1) Nice. This is more concise than my answer.

Let $(X,||\cdot||)$ denote the Banach space. Note that $(Y,||\cdot||)$ and $(Z,||\cdot||)$ are both Banach spaces. So the product $Y \times Z =\{(y,z):y\in Y,z\in Z\}$ is also a Banach space with norm $||(y,z)||:=||y||+||z||$.
Define the linear map $T(y,z)=y+z$. Then by the assumption $X=Y+Z$, the map is surjective. If $Y\cap Z=\{0\}$, then the map is injective. So each $x$ has a unique representation $y+z$. Also $||T(y,z)||=||y+z||\leq ||y||+||z||=||(y,z)||$. So it's bounded. Then by the Bounded Inverse Theorem, there exists $C$ such that $||y||+||z||\leq C||y+z||$.
If $Y\cap Z\neq \{0\}$, note that the kernel of the map is given by $\{(y,-y):y\in Y\cap Z\}$. Thus, by the universal property for quotient spaces, we get the bounded bijective map $\overline{T}:(Y \times Z)/\ker(T)\to X$ from the Banach space $(Y \times Z)/\ker(T)$ with the quotient norm. Fix an $x\in X$.
So, as every $x\in X$ has it's preimage $[y,z]$ (which is a coset in $Y \times Z$) in the quotient space, we have by the Bounded Inverse Theorem, $||[y,z]||\leq C||x||$.
Now what is the norm $||[y,z]||$? It is $\inf_{m\in [y,z]}||m||$.
By definition of infimum, there exists a $m\in[y,z]$ (depending on $\epsilon$) such that $||m||\leq ||[y,z]||+\epsilon$. By chosing $\epsilon=||[y,z]||$, there exists $m\in[y,z]$ such that $||m||\leq 2||[y,z]||$.
Thus, you have $||\frac{m}{2}||\leq ||[y,z]||\leq C||x||$ or $||m||\leq 2C||x||$
But, as $m$ is of the form $(y',z')$ and since $m\in [y,z]$, $T(m)=y'+z'=x$
Thus this $x$ has a representation $(y',z')$ in $Y \times Z$ such that $y'+z'=x$ and $$||m||=||y'||+||z'||\leq 2C||x||=2C||y'+z'||$$
As $x$ was arbitrary, this holds for all $x\in X$. So you can choose your $C$ such that $C=2||T^{-1}||$ and you'll get the claim that each $x$ has a representation $y+z$ such that $||y||+||z||\leq C||x||$

Is this notation for the product space common? I only know $Y \times Z$.

I used this in order to avoid writing $\times$. It's only for typing ease @MartinBrandenburg.

I see. I can change it for you then ;), just to avoid any confusion with, say, the ordered pair. Generally speaking I think it is best not to introduce different notations for the same thing, in particular when they overlap with something else.

@MartinBrandenburg Thanks Martin, please feel free to edit my answer in any way you see fit.

There are already nice answers, but one can argue as follows. In general, if $Y$ and $Z$ are Banach spaces embedded in a common topological vector space (in this case, $X$), then $Y+Z$ forms a Banach space with the "sum norm"
$$\lVert x\rVert_{Y+Z}=\inf(\lVert y\rVert_Y+\lVert z\rVert_Z), $$
where the infimum ranges over all decompositions $x=y+z$ with $y\in Y$ and $z\in Z$. (Prove it!)
In this case, $X$ has two norms $\lVert\cdot\rVert_{Y+Z}$ and $\lVert\cdot\rVert_X$, both of which makes $X$ a Banach space. Obviously, $\lVert\cdot\rVert_X\leq\lVert\cdot\rVert_{Y+Z}$, so the open mapping theorem yields the conclusion.
(In fact, the sum norm is nothing but the quotient norm of $Y\times Z$, equipped with the norm $\lVert(y,z)\rVert=\lVert y\rVert+\lVert z\rVert$, modded out by the closed subspace $\{(x,-x):x\in Y\cap Z\}$. Thus this proof is essentially a rephrasement of the other answers.)

The norm is reminiscent of Rockafellar's infimal convolution.
